# Java Program multiples of a number

Tags: java

"Write a snippet of Java code that adds every multiple of 21, starting with 642331 down to 21 to an unidentified `ArrayList` named "values" "

I have alot of issues with this, but here is my code. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
for (int =0 ; i = 642331; i++)
{
  values [i] = 21*i ;
}
```

Comment: There's alot sintax error there :-/

Comment: instead of `i=` should be `i<`

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan and instead of i=, it should be int i = :-)

Comment: Someone will show you the correct syntax, but in the future, you will want to first read your book. You can't guess at programming, and you're doing an awful lot of guessing above.

Comment: But if it's an ArrayList you should use `.add(21*i)` not `[i] = 21*i`

Comment: Also no need for `i = 0;`. You can start from 1.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this implementation.

```
for (int =642331; i > 0; --i)
    {
      values [i] = 21*i ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
ArrayList<Long> values = new ArrayList<>(); // not sure if required by question
for (long l= 642331 / 21; l > 0; --l) {
    values.add(l * 21);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
for (int i =642331 ; i>= 21; i--)
{
  values [i] = 21*i ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **forget to declare** the `i` variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 642331; i++)
    {
      values [i] = 21*i ;
    }
```